# phpMyAdmin is logging in automatically

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I downloaded phpMyAdmin, and when I go to it via `localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin` it logs me in automatically. (Even the first time I even went to it I was logged in automatically) I don't want it to. I went into `config.inc.php` (I made one from `config.sample.inc.php`) And there isn't even lines for making a username and password.

How can I add in code so I can set a username and password, and how can I make phpMyAdmin not login automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Either

1. You have a password manager and that save it for you
2. Every single web browser will offer to save username/passwords on your behalf.  Once it is saved, you can be logged in automatically.

You have to view the saved passwords and delete the one for myphpadmin.

Comment: I never logged in to phpMyAdmin. When I first got it and went to it I was logged in automatically.

Comment: Then you don't have user authentication enabled

Comment: How do I enable it?